# Downloading Proxy Script

Tags: autoproxy

When navigating to some sites in my internal network I noticed that Chrome flashes the message below.  I believe this is related to WPAD.

How can I view the actual proxy script that is downloaded?  I don't see it in the network tab in the chrome tools.

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate bit more. What are you doing, when, with what.

Comment: This is most likely caused by a chrome extension, maybe something like an auto-proxy script?

Comment: Why the down votes? This message appears whenever you connect to a new network, and there is nothing to elaborate. I have seen this on both mainline and canary.

Comment: @leepfrog It is not caused by an extension. Chrome does this by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you type `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` in the address bar, the proxy auto-configuration script that's currently being used should be listed.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Go to the `Change Proxy settings` pop-up and then to `LAN settings`. There would be 2 sections. The lower section may contain the "auto proxy settings".

Otherwise, in the upper section there will be an input box where the path to the proxyScript may be written. If it is, you may be able to go to that path in normal file explorer and check out the proxy details.

Comment: So, these proxy settings are related to the OS?

Comment: Dunno about that, but yes, these _can_ be set by your sys admin. Atleast that's how I found out. So, _might_ be OS related.

Answer (score 3):

Open Chrome Settings page Alt+E then S -> Show Advanced Settings -> In the Network Click Change Proxy Settings -> In The Popup -> Lan Settings -> UnCheck Automatically detect settings...

This Worked for me...

Comment: The question is _How can I view the actual proxy script that is downloaded_ **not** how to disable auto-detect